# PDO rowcount used often

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mariadb, rowcount

I often use the function rowCount of PDO like this for example:

```
$sql = $dataBase->prepare('SELECT email, firstname, lastname
                           FROM pr__user
                           WHERE id = :id');

$sql->execute(array('id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));
$rowCount = $sql->rowCount();
```

It al the time worked fine but I saw in the PHP manual:

> If the last SQL statement executed by the associated PDOStatement was
>   a SELECT statement, some databases may return the number of rows
>   returned by that statement. However, this behaviour is not guaranteed
>   for all databases and should not be relied on for portable
>   applications.
>   http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

It works fine with MySQL and MariaDB so I kept on using it. As I use it an application I wish portable, should I modify my code?

Comment: If it ain't broke, then why fix it?

Comment: "... should I modify my code?" - This is opinion based. But you can rewrite your question to something like "What are the risks of ...".

Answer (score 1):

I never ask for the row count.  Querying always returns an array of result rows (in some format), I can simply ask how many rows in the array -- such as with PHP's `count(..)` function.

Comment: You do a `fetckALL()`  for that? Like this:  `$result = $sql->fetchALL();` ?

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is that PDO is an interface to [many different databases](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php), not just MySQL. They make no guarantees that the function will return the same sort of values on completely different back-ends.

This is what "for portable applications" means: If you want your code to run universally on an arbitrary database you may need to avoid using that function. If that's not the case, you're not writing generic library code, you can depend on MySQL's particular behaviour.

Just be sure to test whatever you're doing to ensure that assumption is reasonable.

Comment: Yes but I mean in some comments of this function people say `MySQL does not seem to return anything in rowCount `. But now it's working! So maybe it's working for most of databases, isn't it?

Comment: I think it's just a warning so people won't be surprised when PDO + a 2002 version of Sybase ends up producing unexpected results.

Answer (score 0):

Rather, it's just [pointless and superfluous](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#count). You are bloating your code for no reason.

From your example it is evident that you are going to use the data selected (otherwise there is no point in selecting email). So it means that you can use that data instead of row count all the way. Assuming the next operator would be fetch(), you can omit rowCount()

```
$sql = $dataBase->prepare('SELECT email, firstname, lastname
                       FROM pr__user
                       WHERE id = :id');

$sql->execute(array('id' => $_SESSION['user_id']));
$user = $sql->fetch();
if ($user) { ...
```

and *from now on you can use `$user` in the every single condition* where $rowCount has been used. Simply because you don't actually need a count here, but rather a *boolean flag* for which purpose an array would serve as good as an integer.

Even in a case when you don't need email but only to know whether a user exists, you can simply select just `1` scalar value and then fetch it - so your code remains uniform.